# Delphi set Panel visible after post

Tags: delphi

this is my code:

```
  if DRelatiebeheer.ContactpersoonID.Post = Action then
    KJSMDBGrid1.RefreshData;
  KJPanel4.Visible := true;
```

my question is how can i set the panel on visible when the post is succesfully ended.

I dont know how to fix it, tried many ways but didn't find a solution for the problem.

I think the code doesn't work, because i put it invisible on the `OnGetCellParams` event.

And I only want to set the last panel visible when the information is posted

```
procedure TFRelatiebeheer.KJSMDBGrid1GetCellParams(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if DRelatiebeheer.ACCID.AsInteger <= 0 then
    KJPanel3.Visible := false;
    KJPanel4.Visible := false;
  else
  begin
    KJPanel3.Visible := true;
end;
```

this is my OnGetCellParams event, this is the other

```
procedure TFRelatiebeheer.SaveCancel(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if (DRelatiebeheer.CID.State in [dsEdit, dsInsert]) then
    DRelatiebeheer.CID.Post;
  DRelatiebeheer.AID.Post;
  if DRelatiebeheer.CID.Post = Action then
    KJSMDBGrid1.RefreshData;
    KJPanel4.Visible := true;
  end;
```

Comment: Not very clear what you are asking. You didn't actually describe the problem. Do note that `KJPanel4.Visible := true` is outside the `if`

Comment: i have 2 if statements one on `OnGetCellParams` event and the other one for the afterpost

Comment: Dont know how to declare it better sorry if you cant do anything with it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the answer can be found in my first comment to your question. Let's look at this code:

```
procedure TFRelatiebeheer.SaveCancel(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if (DRelatiebeheer.CID.State in [dsEdit, dsInsert]) then
    DRelatiebeheer.CID.Post;
  DRelatiebeheer.AID.Post;
  if DRelatiebeheer.CID.Post = Action then
    KJSMDBGrid1.RefreshData;
    KJPanel4.Visible := true;
  end;
```

The indentation is off. You think that you are setting `KJPanel4.Visible` inside the `if`, but you are not. Let's correct the indentation:

```
procedure TFRelatiebeheer.SaveCancel(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if (DRelatiebeheer.CID.State in [dsEdit, dsInsert]) then
    DRelatiebeheer.CID.Post;
  DRelatiebeheer.AID.Post;
  if DRelatiebeheer.CID.Post = Action then
    KJSMDBGrid1.RefreshData;
  KJPanel4.Visible := true;
end;
```

Do you see what has happened?

Correct this with `begin/end`:

```
procedure TFRelatiebeheer.SaveCancel(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if (DRelatiebeheer.CID.State in [dsEdit, dsInsert]) then
    DRelatiebeheer.CID.Post;
  DRelatiebeheer.AID.Post;
  if DRelatiebeheer.CID.Post = Action then
  begin
    KJSMDBGrid1.RefreshData;
    KJPanel4.Visible := true;
  end;
end;
```

For what it is worth, where I work, our coding standard demands the use of [compound statements](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/Declarations_and_Statements#Compound_Statements), with `begin/end`, and forbids the use of the single statement variant. In the past 15 years since we introduced this rule, we have not once encountered this mistake. Niklas Wirth knew that he had got it wrong and corrected the mistake in Modula-2. But it's simple enough to avoid the problem yourself just by forsaking single statement syntax.

---

Update, as you and others point out, `if DRelatiebeheer.CID.Post = Action then` looks dubious. I honestly don't know enough about the classes that you are using to recommend a solution to that problem.

Comment: @DavidHefferman One more question when i start up the programm now he gives me the eroor for Incompatible types at row `if DRelatiebeheer.ContactpersoonID.Post = Action then`

Comment: I'm not sure about that. I don't actually know the types of any of the variables in the code.

Comment: @DavidHefferman OK thanks for the answer. Going to try out some different things

Comment: @Daan, I'm not sure which TDataSet you use (CID), but `Post` is a method with no return result so `DRelatiebeheer.CID.Post = Action` does not look right to me.

Comment: @kobik i already thought that but dont know how to check it another way